# Get group members in replication metadata from directory services namespace

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to get a groups member list or even the members attribute from [AttributeMetadata Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.attributemetadata(v=vs.110).aspx) like the following:

```
var directoryContext = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.DirectoryServer, "dc", "user", "pw");
var metadata = DomainController.GetDomainController(directoryContext).GetReplicationMetadata("groupDN");

foreach (AttributeMetadata attribute in metaData.Values)
{
  string name = attribute.Name
}
```

The problem is that the members list and the multi value attribute 'members' are no part of the metaData.Values collection. Does anyone know how to get them? Or is there an another way to get the members metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Member metadata is stored in msds-replvaluemetadata attribute of an object. This attribute is designed to store replication info for each member (DN) either added or removed. This rule applies to all DN based attributes (member, manager, etc.). You can query the attribute and manually parse the data

Comment: If my groups member list is too large my query result collection is empty... do you know why?

Comment: How many members does your group contain? Please open up Active Directory Users and Computers, go to properties of the problematic group, switch to attribute editor tab (advanced features mode) and find the msds-replvaluemetadata attribute. Does it contain value?

Comment: Q/A there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636496/get-replication-value-meta-data-with-directorysearcher-for-large-adgroups