# Get replication value meta data with DirectorySearcher for large ADGroups

Tags: c#, active-directory, directorysearcher

I'm trying to get the replication value meta data from an ADGroup with over 20.000 members.
   Here's the code:

```
const string replicationData = "msDS-ReplValueMetaData";

var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{dn}");

var directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry, 
                                              null, 
                                              new string[]
                                                         {
                                                             replicationData
                                                         });


var propertyResultCollection = (directorySearcher.FindOne()).Properties[replicationData];
```

It works pretty fine for small groups but if the groups have too much members i just receive an empty collection.

Comment: Ok, created the group with 20K members. DirectorySearcher returns: msds-replvaluemetadata, which is empty, msds-replvaluemetadata;range=0-999, which contains first 1000 attribute values. To get all values you need to use technique called range retrieval (attribute values paging) as AD can't return you 20K values in a single response. Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367017(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Great job! Thanks!